# Kasina meditation details

Tags: meditation

From what I can gather, kasina meditation involves staring at the kasina initially, and then attempting to generate/visaulize it as a mental image. I *believe* this is how the Visudhimagga describes it. Are there any other older meditation manuals, perhaps like the Vimutimagga, or Abhidhamma, which describe kasina meditation in detail?

However, I have seen other sources which say one should focus on the retinal after-image.

What is the more traditional approach? I am aware that kasina meditation is not described in detail in the suttas. I would also prefer not this question to be derailed by the discussion of whether or not they were a late invention.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The fire kasina is the only one I know that uses an actual retinal afterimage.  It's probably the only one where that would even work, truth be told.  If you give it a try - a candle works very well - when you close your eyes you will notice a very distinctive, visual impression where the candle was.  Plainly, this just doesn't happen with the others.  If this is your first sojourn into kasina practice, I would actually recommend the fire kasina for that very reason.  It is *much* easier to work with a physical sensation than the visualized disks called for by the others.

But yes, what you describe is the gist of it.  It sounds mystical, but it's actually quite practical.  I also have to say that as a meditative method, I am a devoted fan despite being a Zen student of nearly 20 years.  I think you'll find that they demand that you very quickly learn to relax, let go, and quiet your mind.  If you don't it will be very difficult to maintain a stable image of the kasina. You also get immediate feedback on your practice.  You know, from moment to moment, how well you're doing and how stable your mind is.  If there's no kasina, there's no samadhi!

Comment: Do you have a canonical reference for the fact that the fire kasina uses a retinal afterimage?

Comment: There's none I'm aware of.  But try it.  It's fairly obvious.  The rods and cones in your eyes don't pick up enough light from a drawn kasina for that to work.  One thing I will say is that as you keep that retinal afterimage in your mind's eye, it will change - usually getting darker, turning red, etc.  Don't try to maintain the initial impression.  Just let it do its thing.

Comment: Did you try it yet?

Comment: Who's Daniel Ingram?